# Compactly supported function.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can anyone explain me the features of a compactly supported functions behave when they are compactly supported. I am learning PDE and I come across it very often.

For example : When we define weak derivatives i.e
$\int_U uD^\alpha f=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_U vf$
, why do we take a function $f$ to be compactly supported ?

I wonder if it is has to do with the non-differentiability of $u$ at some point in the domain ?

Looking forward. Thanks

Comment: A *function* $f$, not a *set* is compactly supported. This means that the closure of the set $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}$ is a compact set.

Comment: @ Alex , as i have come across behaviour of compactly supported functions is very useful and notable. Can you explain a bit with some example or give a an idea where i can learn about it . :)

Comment: Please read the title and body of the question again, it could use some proofreading :) Also, could you please include your comment in the body of your question? As it stands the only answer to your question is: the only feature all compactly supported functions share is that they are, well, compactly supported...

Comment: @Vedananda It's a very big topic, I'm not sure how this could be given a single answer.

Comment: I downvoted. "This question does not show any research effort." I encourage you to edit your question, give it some background and direction, and to be a bit more specific. I'm confident that if you put some more time into it, more users here would spend time on writing an answer.

Comment: @ mixedmath , i agree , i wanted to rush through it :P

Comment: @Vedananda: Do not forget to at least upvote the answers.

Comment: @ timur of course .

Comment: @Vedananda: thanks!

Comment: "Can anyone explain me all the features...?" In my opinion, *no*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot explain all the features, but the defining property of a compactly supported function $f$ defined on an open set $\Omega$ is that there exists a compact set $K$ in $\Omega$ such that $f(x)=0$ if $x\not\in K$. This is useful since for instance when you do integration by parts on $f$, the boundary terms vanish. If $g$ is any function, you can get a compactly supported function $fg$ by multiplying it by $f$. This is called a *cut-off* process.

In the PDE context, cut-off functions are usually smooth, this means that, as mentioned in the comment, all derivatives of $f$ will be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Plus you get uniform continuity.